# Auto-Clear Script in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script for a google form, so that it will delete all cells from A2 to J50. I need any cells except for the top-most row to be deleted every sunday (I think I can just use the event trigger, so I should just need the code to wipe all but that top row).

Right now, I have:
[image]

It is filled out with my correct sheet name, but I just get:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: A [time driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) may be more useful if you want it to run every Sunday

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

The value of 'sheet' is set to null, because there's an error in the name of the sheet you provided to getSheetByName.

Double-check whether you've copied the right sheet name. Your code is fine otherwise.

Comment: what would it be if my sheet name is exactly: 

SPCH-1311-081 Weekly Check-Up

Comment: Is that the name of the entire spreadsheet, or the sheet tab? It should be just the name of that particular sheet tab.